# Obtener propiedades de clase genérica - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Colegas, tengo el siguiente problema:

Actualmente estoy construyendo un método genérico que exporte datos a Excel. Entre los parámetros que le envío a dicha función se encuentran el encabezado, los datos y el nombre del archivo

> private bool CreateExcel(IEnumerable headers,
>   IEnumerable list, string fileName)

Hice las correspondientes pruebas y funciona perfecto. El **problema** es que estoy obteniendo las propiedades de dicha clase *CourseToExcel* mediante `PropertyDescriptorCollection, pero como pudieron notar estoy pasando la clase *CourseToExcel* de forma explícita.

Lo que necesito es pasar ese parámetro de forma dinámica para que acepte una clase con cualquier estructura y al mismo tiempo no tener conflictos al obtener las propiedades de dicha clase genérica.

Adjunto el método completo para quien lo necesite:

```
private bool CreateExcel(IEnumerable<string> headers, IEnumerable<CourseToExcel> list, string fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                using (ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage())
                {
                    excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Detalles");
                    ExcelWorksheet sheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets["Detalles"];

                    #region HEADER
                    int posHeader = 1;
                    foreach(string header in headers)
                    {
                        sheet.Cells[1, posHeader].Value = header;
                        sheet.Cells[1, posHeader].Style.Font.Bold = true;
                        posHeader++;
                    }
                    #endregion

                    #region ROWS
                    int posRow = 2;
                    int col = 0;

                    PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(CourseToExcel));

                    foreach (PropertyDescriptor p in properties)
                    {
                        col++;
                        foreach (var item in list.Select(x => p.GetValue(x)).ToList())
                        {
                            sheet.Cells[posRow, col].Value = item;
                            posRow++;
                        }
                        posRow = 2;
                    }
                    #endregion

                    sheet.Cells[sheet.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();

                    FileInfo excelFile = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), $"{fileName}.xlsx"));
                    excel.SaveAs(excelFile);
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

Como siempre, cualquier información se agradece.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 private bool CreateExcel<T>(IEnumerable<string> headers, IEnumerable<T> list, string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            using (ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage())
            {
                excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Detalles");
                ExcelWorksheet sheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets["Detalles"];

                #region HEADER
                int posHeader = 1;
                foreach (string header in headers)
                {
                    sheet.Cells[1, posHeader].Value = header;
                    sheet.Cells[1, posHeader].Style.Font.Bold = true;
                    posHeader++;
                }
                #endregion

                #region ROWS
                int posRow = 2;
                int col = 0;

                PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));

                foreach (PropertyDescriptor p in properties)
                {
                    col++;
                    foreach (var item in list.Select(x => p.GetValue(x)).ToList())
                    {
                        sheet.Cells[posRow, col].Value = item;
                        posRow++;
                    }
                    posRow = 2;
                }
                #endregion

                sheet.Cells[sheet.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();

                FileInfo excelFile = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), $"{fileName}.xlsx"));
                excel.SaveAs(excelFile);
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }
    }
```